# Difference Between sorting in single line and multiple line in python3 please have a look at the code below

Tags: python-3.x

1. 

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        marksheet.append([name,score])
        
    second_lowest = sorted(list(set(marks for name, marks in marksheet)))[1]
```

In this code I am getting a list like [20,30], that's why I am able to select the first element i.e 20

2)

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        marksheet.append([name,score])
        
  for name, marks in marksheet:
        second_lowest = sorted(list(set(marks)))[1]
```

But in this case, my list is in the form of
[20]
[30]
[40]  because of that, I am not able to select them in index wise and error " index out of range " is popping up

Please help me debug this, it's making me frustated

Comment: In the first code piece you are doing a comprehension to construct a set `set(marks for name, marks in marksheet)` which is then converted to list and sorted. In the second snippet, you are doing assignment of `second_lowest` variable in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, remember `marks` in the loop is a single value and not a list. So it is normal to get a list of one element each iteration e.g., [20][30][40] because you used the set and sorted functions to convert a single value to a list from 20 to [20]. *Also, you should use the append function to add values to a list instead of the assignment operator which used with assigning values with variables. Thus, you can use second_lowest.append(marks) in the loop.*

I tried to solve the problem and optimize it for both cases:

```
marksheet = []

for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        marksheet.append([name,score])

name,score = zip(*marksheet)
second_lowest = sorted(set(score))[1]
```